# How can i hide this css object?

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to react-js or css and i want to hide a css object.

This is the code

[image]

I tried to hide (make it unclickable) the object with this code

```
.react-aria9431256528-7 
{
display: none;
}
```

but this only works temporary. Every time i load the site, the id changes. How can i reference this object in  way that it will always work? I was thinking about the aria-label since it is constant but how to i reference it?

Is there a better way than just to hide it?

Comment: You should share a [mcve] of the React source to get more meaningful assistance.  Generally, for something like this, you'd either drive the hiding/showing logic in JSX or assign a stable class in the JSX you could use to target the element.

Comment: it depends on the library you're using. You probably installed some react library and you use it, they render it with different id every time, but you can probably wrap it with your own div and apply the `display: none`

Comment: @OmriAttiya
This is not my code, i'm just trying to override an existing website and disable some elements i don't want. How should the wrapper look like?

Comment: @Helyx In your code(image) you dont have a class with the pattern `react-area...`. But you have a id with this pattern. It is a mistake / typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `aria-label` attribute is unique, you can use the attribute selector syntax (`[attr="value"]`) as follows:

```css
[aria-label="Help"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" aria-label="Help">Help</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for example.

```
a[id^="react-"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```css
a[id^="react-"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a id="react-area1">1</a>
  <a id="react-area1">2</a>
  <a id="react-area1">3</a>
  <a id="area1">4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: There are no elements with a class of `react-*` in the OP's example.

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: @BenM You are right! I changed it. Thank you for hint!!

Comment: @Helyx It hides all anchor tags which id starts with `react-`

Answer (score 0):

Is it the link (a href='...') that you're trying to hide? You could use the aria-label as already said. Here is another solution :
I've noticed that there is a parent div with a class "dropddown". You could target your link with css like below:

```
.dropddown > a {
  display:none;
}
```

That should do it normally. If not add the important flag :

```
.dropddown > a {
  display:none !important;
}
```

PS, don't forget to fix the naming of the class dropddown by the way (one d) => "dropdown". That makes me believe that you have control over it ;).